# display element from php page to html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I created a simple custom CMS using some instructional videos from youtube. However, I wanted to display those contents from my CMS php page to an HTML file. I was able to do so (so i thought) but when I tried opening on a different pc, instead of displaying the content, it is showing the login form of the CMS. As it turns out, unless I log in to the CMS on that computer, it won't show the content.

Here is the script code I used to display the content:

```
$(document).ready(function()  { 
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://**********/SubPage.php?ID=3", 
        xhrFields: {withCredentials:true}, 
        success: function(data){
            var dt=$(data).find("#phpContent").html();
            $("#htmlDIV").html(dt);}
        });
});
```

i've used access-control-allow-origin & credentials on the source page and i'm wondering if there's anyway that i can send the login details (securely) to display the php page content on page load.

Comment: why don't you encrypt the login details and send or md5sum or use oAuth like key to show the content? Or create a no-access-control page?

Comment: The question isn't about including the credentials, @HilmiErdemKEREN. I think that the success parameter needs to be followed by a command to exit the script. If success is false, the script doesn't exit and another part that is still to be added would be able to display the standard contents.

Comment: @mark From the original question : i'm wondering if there's anyway that i can send the login details (securely) to display the php page content on page load

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN Sure you can, but you'll need to post your own question for that. (I think there are quote a few answers about that on SO already).

Comment: @mark Man please read the question. I quoted this.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you misunderstand the question, @HilmiErdemKEREN